# carrying out JUnit Testing with complex code

Tags: java, junit

Can someone guide me on how to carry out JUnit testing in java. I have watched youtube videos but I am finding it hard to understand the concept of getting more complext code unit tested.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYnMyi81hrs
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KX6CgjHciXU

For example, how can I test this code?

```
text = "I was chosen";
JButton button1 = new Jbutton("");
JButton button2 = new Jbutton("");
JButton button3 = new Jbutton("");
List<JButton> buttons = Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3);
Random r = new Random();
buttons.get(r.nextInt(buttons.size())).setText(text);
```

and also test large pieces of code that are in methods and being called elsewhere.

edited:

package testing;

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test {

    String sign = "!";
    String notSign = "-";

    public test(){
        String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please write a sign: ");

        if (test.equals("!")){
            sign1();
        }
            else if (test.equals("-")){
                sign2();
            }
        }

    public void sign1(){
        sign = "*";
    }
    public void sign2(){
        notSign = "/";
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new test();
    }
}
```

edited 2:

The reason, I wanted to know how Junit test works is because, I am working on this project for my collage and after finishing my code, it is producing bugs and I have read the code over and over again and have no clue where the bugs are coming from. Is there is better way of finding bugs and fixing them?

Comment: Firstly, this is a very broad question. "How to unit test" is the subject of many books. With regards to your example, it's not possible to advise on how to test snippets without seeing (at least) the method they are part of. Without that, we don't know the results that are produced or the external state that is manipulated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to test in that code? And is it a reasonable ROI to test it?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you want to test? In case of the buttons you could call the getText method of the button and see if it is the expected value (http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. That code is just an example, I am not exactly sure how Junit testing works and what kind of code I need to have in order to Junit test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, IMO, I don't really see any positive gain from unit testing GUI stuff. (totally depends on the situation though)

Secondly, you should test methods:

e.g. Take the method:

```
public int add(int i, int j) {
   return i+j;
}
```

Now, to unit test this code, we would do:

```
public void shouldReturn5WhenAdding2And3 {
  // When
  int result = testSubject.add(2, 3);       

  // Then
  assertEquals(result, 5);
}
```

Now onto your code:
I'd suggest taking the following code out and placing into it's own method:

```
Random r = new Random();
buttons.get(r.nextInt(buttons.size())).setText(text);
```

e.g.

```
public void printTextOnRandomButton(List<JButton> buttons) {
    Random r = new Random();
    buttons.get(r.nextInt(buttons.size())).setText(text);
}
```

Then you could pass in a list of buttons in your unit test and assert that one of them has text:

```
public void oneOfButtonsShouldHaveText() {
  // Given
  List<JButton> buttons = testSubject.getButtons();
  // You don't have to get the list of buttons from the tested class, you could
  // create a list of buttons within the test.
  String text = "I was chosen";

  // When
  testSubject.printTextOnRandomButton(buttons);

  // Then
  assertTrue(button1.getText().equals(text) || button2.getText().equals(text) || button3.getText().equals(text));
}
```

EDIT: I might be inclined to use XOR instead of OR in the assertion.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the breakdown of how its done. I have 1 question, say for example, I have a method that is using global variables, when unit testing would I need to copy along the variables to or just the method?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post, sorry for the wait.

Comment: Not a problem! I'm not quite sure you've completely grasped the notion of unit testing (specifically using JUnit). Each class should have a test class which exercises the code within. E.g. a Math class and a MathJUnitTest class. Lets say that the Math class has an add and a subtract method. You would then create tests for those methods in the MathJUnitTest class. It's worth reading up on unit testing a little more, perhaps watching a few more videos and working with simpler code examples. Sorry I can't be anymore help.

Comment: I have also edited my post now, saying what I am after Junit testing, are there any better ways of finding where bugs are being produced from, which line and fix them?

Comment: You'll want to use a debugging tool for that. Eclipse has one built in. Step through the code until you can see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you could test that the name of one of the button equals text:

```
assertTrue(button1.getText().equals(text) || button2.getText().equals(text) || button3.getText().equals(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been there and it is difficult at first but with practice you can get better. Here's a link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/index.htm that I used and you can also learn from it.

Comment: Hi, the link is very useful. Are there any other sort of testing in java?

Comment: My dear friend, you should really focus on coding and worry less about testing. There are hundreds of tutorials available for testing; just google them. And yes IDEs also provide testing facilities. Moreover you can use automated tools for testing. Also, you can write Python scripts for testing

Comment: The main reason why I wanted to ask is, I am working on this program for my collage project and I have finished it but I it is producing few bugs and I have read my code plenty of times but I can't figure out where the bugs are coming from.